# How to remove item from DevExpress MapControl?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to remove selected item from MapControl. I do:

```
MapItem t = (MapItem)vectorItemsLayer.SelectedItem;
SqlGeometryItem sourceItem = (SqlGeometryItem)vectorItemsLayer.GetItemSourceObject(t);
sqlGeometryItemStorage.Items.Remove(sourceItem);
```

And got error in `GetItemSourceObject`:

```
Can not cast 'DevExpress.XtraMap.MapPolyline' to 'DevExpress.XtraMap.SqlGeometryItem'
```

In [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraMap.VectorItemsLayer.GetItemSourceObject.method) i see that method takes `MapItem` and return `SqlGeometryItem`.

So what can i miss?
And maybe there is more optimal way to remove item from map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to get SqlGeometryItem corresponding to MapItem displayed on a map](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T741967/how-to-get-sqlgeometryitem-corresponding-to-mapitem-displayed-on-a-map)

> There is not a  way to get SqlGeometryItem corresponding to a specific
>   MapItem right now. The DevExpress support team is investigating this issue and suggest you follow the above support ticket to get the update about the solution of the required functionality.